# How to add control beside existing control in a rad grid cell dynamically

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a rad grid that is being created programmatically, I add a textbox control to a cell, and if I add another control(say an image),it appears below the textbox, what should I do for the image to appear beside the textbox, I tried "display:inline", but did not work. I believe this is happening because the text box with is equal to the column width,but i do not have an option to fix the column width since the entire grid,columns and rows are dynamic. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any screenshots please add those things to give more clarity on this question.
If possible you can reduce the size of textbox and image, so that both can accommodate in same column.

Comment: I reduced the size of the text box and the image is appearing beside the textbox now,but it is looking odd,is there any way to retain the textbox size and align the image next to it?And i had applied 'vertical-align:top' to the image, but its not applying, when I check in developer tools, vertical align is striked out in IE11, it is sitting at the bottom right corner of the textbox, I want it top right corner of the textbox.

Comment: As of my knowledge, in IE browser to use vertical align attribute you have to mention "min-height" or "height" attribute  for that particular div. Then only it will get reflect.